# CSS - Set total width of all child elements equal to their parent

Tags: javascript, html, css, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm trying to create a square that contains rectangles that each contain a word. The total width of each child rectangle should equal the parent, but the problem is that I don't know the order or length of each of the words, and using a search filter I can dynamically update the list client-side, thus I can't statically assign a width/`padding`/margins to each of the containing rectangles. To illustrate my problem, here's my current code, along with a screenshot showing what I currently have.

```
<div class="index">
  <!-- heading, filter input and other stuff here -->
  <div class="books">
    <div class="book">Lorem</div>
    <div class="book">Ipsum</div>
    <div class="book">is</div>
    <div class="book">simply</div>
    <div class="book">dummy</div>
    <!-- rest of the book divs here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

I tried moving the word rectangles around in an image editor to show what I'm trying to achieve but it turned into a mess. Basically, I want to "justify align" the rectangles within their parent square so that the rectangles are flush with all the parent's sides. I'd prefer to use `width`/`padding` over margins, because I'd like to maintain a `1px` margin around all of them. I.e. the words' gray backgrounds should increase in width. If you need to see a picture of what I'm trying to achieve, let me know and I'll try to move them around again.

Also note that I'm using Vue.js and Vuetify (the word rectangles are generated by a `v-for`), so if your answer includes Vue/Vuetify specific solutions, I'd be more than happy. But for the sake of future readers, I'll also gladly accept vanilla HTML/CSS/JS solutions.

Please also give us the name of this effect (if it has one).

Comment: I usually use CSS grid for things like this:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Look at the "Special Functions and Keywords" example in the link above specifically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a small fiddle using `flexbox` at https://jsfiddle.net/saksham_malhotra/52nz7rpf/

This helps you to spread out the book names to cover each row till the end.

the pseudo `after` element is used to leave the empty space at the last instead of making the last few boxes cover the whole row.

Comment: Oh wow, that's fantastic! I'm gonna leave it unaccepted for a while longer, but will accept it if no one else shows up. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just flex the container div and apply a flex to the child class

```css
.books {
  background-color: #333;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.book {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 10px;
  flex: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="index">
  <!-- heading, filter input and other stuff here -->
  <div class="books">
    <div class="book">Lorem</div>
    <div class="book">Ipsum</div>
    <div class="book">is</div>
    <div class="book">simply</div>
    <div class="book">dummy</div>
    <div class="book">Lorem</div>
    <div class="book">Ipsum</div>
    <div class="book">is</div>
    <div class="book">simply</div>
    <div class="book">dummy</div>
    <div class="book">Lorem</div>
    <div class="book">Ipsum</div>
    <div class="book">is</div>
    <div class="book">simply</div>
    <div class="book">dummy</div>
    <!-- rest of the book divs here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using CSS Flexbox for this layout behavior, since it's basically a wrapping row with particular alignment rules.

There are lots of Flexbox resources on the web, but I highly recommend "[A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)".

Here's roughly the CSS I think will achieve your desired result:

```
.books {
  /* Flexbox stuff */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  /* Other stuff */
  background-color: lightgray;
}
.book {
  /* Flexbox stuff */
  flex-basis: content;
  /* Other stuff */
  margin: 1px;
  background-color: darkgray;
}
```

Here's a CodePen example using this CSS:
https://codepen.io/Da13Harris/pen/PvePxq